# WPF- LINQ Database doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, insert-update

Im trying to write a WPF application using Linq but while trying to update the database (add new data to it) it doesn't update at all.

I want to add another row when I click a button but it doesn't update the database at all and after checking data it's still empty.

If anyone can help me with that I would be grateful.

```
namespace portiEX
{

    public partial class LentPop : Window
    {
        DataBaseConnectionsDataContext DB = new DataBaseConnectionsDataContext();
        DataBaseConDataContext Con = new DataBaseConDataContext();

        DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;

        string tmp;
        List<string> EQ = new List<string>();
        public LentPop()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            // Combobox with RoomNumbers

            List<Table_Key> dataRoom = DB.Table_Keys.ToList();

            RoomComboBox.ItemsSource = dataRoom;
            RoomComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "ROOM_NUMBER";
            RoomComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER";

            // Combobox with info who took room

            List<EMPLOYEE> dataEmp = DB.EMPLOYEEs.ToList();

            PersonBorrComboBox.ItemsSource = dataEmp;
            PersonBorrComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "NAME_SURNAME";
            PersonBorrComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER";

            // Combobox with Equipment selected

            ListEquipment();
            AddStuffComboBox.ItemsSource = EQ;

            ComboBoxsSupplement();

            //hour
            LblCurrDate.Content = CurrentDate.ToString();


        }

        private void ComboBoxsSupplement()
        {
    enter code here
            // Combobox with hours of return
            HoursLoop(HourofRetComboBox);

            // Combobox with mins of return
            MinLoop(MinsofRetComboBox);
        }

        private void ListEquipment()
        {
            foreach (var s in DB.Equipments)
            {
                if (s.QUANITY != 0)
                {
                    tmp = s.NAME;
                    EQ.Add(tmp);
                }
            }
        }
        private void CancelButt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Con.Tables.InsertOnSubmit(new Table
            {
                Room_Number = decimal.Parse(RoomComboBox.Text),
                Who_Borr = PersonBorrComboBox.Text,
                Borrow_Data = CurrentDate,
                Return_Date = HourofRetComboBox.Text,
                Add_Eq = AddStuffComboBox.Text

            });
            Con.SubmitChanges();

            this.Close();
        }
        public void RentButt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string x = ("Room Number: " + RoomComboBox.Text + "\nWho Borrow: " + PersonBorrComboBox.Text +
                "\nAdd Eq: " + AddStuffComboBox.Text + "\nDate: "  + LblCurrDate.Content +
                "\nReturn time: " + HourofRetComboBox.Text + ":" + MinsofRetComboBox.Text).ToString();

            DB.Borroweds.InsertOnSubmit(new Borrowed
            {
                ROOM_NUMBER = decimal.Parse(RoomComboBox.Text),
                WHO_BORROWED = PersonBorrComboBox.Text,
                ADD_EQUIPMENT = AddStuffComboBox.Text,
                BORROWED_DATE = CurrentDate.ToString(),
                RETURN_DATE = HourofRetComboBox.Text + ":" + MinsofRetComboBox.Text,
            });

            DB.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show(x);
        }
        private void HoursLoop(ComboBox comboBox)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                if(i<10)
                {
                    comboBox.Items.Add("0" + i.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    comboBox.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        private void MinLoop(ComboBox comboBox)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                if(i<10)
                {
                    comboBox.Items.Add("0" + i.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    comboBox.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdnum.png)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="portiEX.Properties.Settings.PortiEXDBsConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PortiEXDBs.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

@Edit
After changing attach~~ to Database im getting error like that:

System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Format ciągu inicjowania jest niezgodny ze specyfikacją, począwszy od indeksu 35.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetDatabaseName(String constr)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Initialize(IDataServices dataServices, Object connection)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Init(Object connection, MappingSource mapping)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrServerOrConnection, MappingSource mapping)
   at portiEX.DataBaseConnectionsDataContext..ctor() in C:\Users\USER\Downloads\portiEXzDB(1)\portiEXzDB\portiEX\DataBaseConnections.designer.cs:line 54
   at portiEX.LoggingPage..ctor() in C:\Users\USER\Downloads\portiEXzDB(1)\portiEXzDB\portiEX\LoggingPage.xaml.cs:line 23

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    portiEX.DataBaseConnectionsDataContext.DataBaseConnectionsDataContext() in DataBaseConnections.designer.cs
    portiEX.LoggingPage.LoggingPage() in LoggingPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Proper design would be to separate your LINQ part from your WPF part. This enables reusing your code, and makes it easier to change it without having to change the users of your code. Testing and debugging will be easier, because you can focus on the update database pare in a small console program. So after you separated it: what is not working? The update database part, or the WPF CancelButtClick part?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse After debugging and everything Update database part isn't working. TO be specific after watching every data contained in comboboxes is selected propertly but it doesn't update database at all. Everything else work perfectly

Comment: Please add details of which database you're using + connection string.

Comment: Added to main post

Comment: As I though, the usual confusion of localdb file location. Just don't use `AttachDbFilename`, but the normal sql server connection string with "database=PortiEXDBs".

Comment: After changing Attach~ to database=PortiEXDBs it shows it looks like it has no connection to DB. What should i change? Create new linq with this DB or something else?

Comment: Can someone help me with error i added to main post? I don't understand it at all